# Dax recursive interval

Tags: powerbi

Is there anyway to convert this TSQL code into DAX?

```sql
/*
The query grabs the first time for each ID (the first SELECT, before the UNION ALL) 
and then recurses, finding the next row for each ID which is at least 15 minutes appart.
*/

/*
drop table if exists example

CREATE TABLE example(
       [ID] [varchar](9) NULL,
       [DTTM] [datetime] NULL
  
) ON [PRIMARY] 

Insert into [example] (ID,DTTM) values 
('123456789','2017-10-05 08:00:00.000'), -- Expected Result
('123456789','2017-10-05 08:05:00.000'), 
('123456789','2017-10-05 08:07:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 08:15:00.000'), -- Expected Result
('123456789','2017-10-05 08:25:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:12:00.000') , -- Expected Result
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:26:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:32:00.000'),  -- Expected Result
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:33:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:34:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:35:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:36:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:37:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:38:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:39:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:40:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:41:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:42:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:43:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:44:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:45:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:46:00.000'),
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:47:00.000'),  -- Expected Result
('123456789','2017-10-05 10:48:00.000')


Insert into [example] (ID,DTTM) values 
('789','2017-10-05 08:00:00.000'), -- Expected Result
('789','2017-10-05 08:05:00.000'), 
('789','2017-10-05 08:07:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 08:15:00.000'), -- Expected Result
('789','2017-10-05 08:25:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:12:00.000') , -- Expected Result
('789','2017-10-05 10:26:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:32:00.000'),  -- Expected Result
('789','2017-10-05 10:33:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:34:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:35:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:36:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:37:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:38:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:39:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:40:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:41:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:42:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:43:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:44:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:45:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:46:00.000'),
('789','2017-10-05 10:47:00.000'),  -- Expected Result
('789','2017-10-05 10:48:00.000')
*/

/*
The query grabs the first time for each ID (the first SELECT, before the UNION ALL) 
and then recurses, finding the next row for each ID which is at least 15 minutes appart.
*/

-- the delta reset when rowcount reach 15 min - ** not a windows of 15 min **
WITH times AS (
    SELECT e.ID, MIN(e.DTTM) AS DTTM
    FROM example e
    GROUP BY e.ID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.ID, r.DTTM
    FROM (
        SELECT e.ID, e.DTTM,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY e.DTTM) AS rn
        FROM example e
        INNER JOIN times t
            ON e.ID = t.ID AND e.DTTM >= DATEADD(mi, 15, t.DTTM)
    ) r
    WHERE r.rn = 1
)
SELECT top 100 percent ID,DTTM
FROM times
ORDER BY ID, DTTM
```

Thanks,
Oded Dror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAX, in itself, isn't recursive. For this particular scenario, you could try the following (which isn't pretty).

Create the following Calculated Columns on your table (in order).

```
_rowId = [ID] & "_" & FORMAT([DTTM], "yymmddTHHmmss")
```

```
_nextInterval15 = 
  var thisD = [DTTM]
  var thisId = [ID]
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      MIN('Data'[_rowId]),
      REMOVEFILTERS(), 
      'Data'[ID] = thisId && 'Data'[DTTM] >= thisD + TIME(0, 15, 0)
    )
```

```
_path = 
  var thisId = [ID]
  var firstId =
    CALCULATE(
      MIN('Data'[_rowId]),
      REMOVEFILTERS(),
      'Data'[ID] = thisId 
    )
  RETURN IF(firstId = [_rowId], PATH('Data'[_rowId], 'Data'[_nextInterval15]) )
```

```
Is Interval 15m = 
  var thisId = [ID]
  var firstPath =
    CALCULATE(
      MIN('Data'[_path]),
      REMOVEFILTERS(),
      'Data'[ID] = thisId 
    )
  RETURN IF(PATHCONTAINS(firstPath, [_rowId]), "Yes" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have PowerBI call a stored procedure in your SQL Server database and use it as a datasource.